# UITableView add Columns?

Tags: uitableview, swift

So far I have this in Swift.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var UITable: UITableView!

    var Item1 = ["Item1","Item1","Item1","Item1"]
    var Item2 = ["Item2","Item2","Item2","Item2"]


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return Item.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = self.UITable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = self.Item [indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

I would like to see if anyone could help me and add var item2 as a column along side the item1 row? Is it possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Please show what you've already tried to create this.

Comment: There are no columns in UITableView - you have to design your UITableViewCells for this...

Comment: @0x7ffffff thats so far and it just shows me in the simulator as one column how do i implement the item2 into this code and make it into 2 columns??

Comment: @Joseandy10 You have to do as Colin suggested and implement custom UITableViewCells. Still, you need to show your attempts at this, and we can help you when you encounter a specific problem.

Comment: @colin how do i implement a UITableViewCells for this example?? help please..new in Swift Programing for IOS.. would really appreciate it.

Comment: could you guys give me an simple example and teach me from there?? this is all i have for the moment..

Comment: @joseandy10 settle down there buddy - have you tried googling "custom UITableViewCell"? do the needful and all that...

Answer (score 0):

you can use a table view inside your cell prototype.then create a subclass of UITableViewCell for that prototype cell which conforms to UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate protocols.make sure you connect all the connection in IB correctly.

```
class CustomCell : UITableViewCell,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
var data :[AnyObject]!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return data.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("innerCell") as UITableViewCell;
    cell.textLabel.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
    return cell
}
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var Item1 = ["Item1","Item1","Item1","Item1"]
var Item2 = ["Item2","Item2","Item2","Item2"]


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Item1.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCell

    cell.label.text = Item1[indexPath.row]
    cell.data = Item2;

    return cell
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: for the main tableview (the one with item1 rows) connect dataSource and delegate of tableView to FirstViewController class and for inner table view (the one with item2 rows) connect dataSource and delegate to the cell prototype. you need to first change the class of cell prototype to CustomCell class